# SecurityException Permission Denial al acceder a los contactos

Tags: java, android

Quiero mostrar los contactos de la agenda pero se me cierra la aplicación al instante. No se donde esta el error:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    TextView txt;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        showContacts();
}

protected void showContacts(){

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;}

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactID,R.id.contactName};
        txt.setText(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.toString());
        //Uri contacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        //Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contacts,projection,null,null,null);
        ListAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main.this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,c,projection,to); 
list.setAdapter(sca);
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: es.exitae.listadocontactos7, PID: 4184
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{es.exitae.listadocontactos7/es.exitae.listadocontactos7.Main}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{98c9152 4184:es.exitae.listadocontactos7/u0a73}
>   (pid=4184, uid=10073) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)

El error continua, yo no entiendo mucho pero por lo poco que veo es que me esta diciendo que añada permisos en el android manifest y eso ya lo tengo hecho

Este es mi android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" ></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: si nos pones también el error nos ayudarás a entender que pasa

Comment: Me esta dando este error

Answer (score 2):

> A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios conceden permisos a las apps mientras se ejecutan, no cuando instalan la app. Este enfoque simplifica el proceso de instalación de la app, ya que el usuario no necesita conceder permisos cuando instala o actualiza la app. También brinda al usuario mayor control sobre la funcionalidad de la app; por ejemplo, un usuario podría optar por proporcionar a una app de cámara acceso a esta, pero no a la ubicación del dispositivo. El usuario puede revocar los permisos en cualquier momento desde la pantalla de configuración de la app.

Si usas algun permiso peligroso deberás pedir autorización en tiempo de ejecución para poder acceder a su funcionalidad, de hecho el Android Studio te marcará como error si accedes a estos permisos sin hacer una comprobación antes.

Lista de permisos peligrosos:

```
READ_CALENDAR
WRITE_CALENDAR
CAMERA
READ_CONTACTS
WRITE_CONTACTS
GET_ACCOUNTS
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
RECORD_AUDIO
READ_PHONE_STATE
CALL_PHONE
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
ADD_VOICEMAIL
USE_SIP
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
BODY_SENSORS
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
RECEIVE_MMS
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Mi recomendación es utilizar alguna librería que facilita las cosas al tener que comprobar si el  usuario aceptó, rechazó, le dio a no volver a ver...

Aquí dejo algunas:

https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Answer (score 1):

como lo has indicado para acceder a los contactos es necesario obtener permisos especiales. Esto es a partir de Android M en adelante, como se indica acá
[Cómo solicitar permisos durante el tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es-419)

Sino quieres usar librerías externas puedes hacerlo mediante códido de la siguiente manera.

Primeramente agregar el permiso en `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Luego en una funcion dentro de tu codigo agregas

```
protected void showContacts(){
    //Si es mayor que android 6 (Marshmallow)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            } 
            else {

                String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;}

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactID,R.id.contactName};
        txt.setText(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.toString());
        //Uri contacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        //Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contacts,projection,null,null,null);
        ListAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main.this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,c,projection,to); 
            list.setAdapter(sca);

            }
        }else{
            //Si es menor que android 6

                String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;}

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactID,R.id.contactName};
        txt.setText(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.toString());
        //Uri contacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        //Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contacts,projection,null,null,null);
        ListAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main.this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,c,projection,to); 
list.setAdapter(sca);
        }

}
```

Finalmente se agrega el metodo `onRequestPermissionsResult()` el cual se encarga de leer la respuesta que de el usuario al momento que tu app solicite el permiso requerido

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Permiso concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Es necesario admitir este permiso para leer los contactos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```